# Check session on every page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in mvc and i try to figured out something.

I have intranet application with login page. I put some stuff in Session and in masterpage on page init events i check

```
If Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
      If Session("someThing") Is Nothing Then Me.SetupSession()
End If
```

This is from web forms, and this is for all page.

How can I do same stuff in MVC 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an Action filter to secure the action method on your controller

if you have a base controller just add the below attribute otherwise you need to add this attribute on all the controller you want to secure

```
[Authorize] 
public class SomeController : DefaultController
{
      public ActionResult SomeAction(){
     }
}
```

this attribute allow you to specify a message as well

```
[Authorize(Message = "Access to the blah blah function requires login. Please login or create an account")]
```

for more info:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you need this, you may write a Global filter to set up the session, or do it in the controller's `Initialize()` method.